# How do I connect my ESP32 cam to my old modem without using Wi-Fi?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, communication

I have an Arduino ESP32 cam that I want to use as a bird cam. I want to use my old Orcon wireless modem to connect with this cam. I will connect with cable from my computer to this modem. As my existing Wi-Fi is running on 5Ghz, I cannot connect to it with this cam. So I need some pointers on how to do. Thanks.

Comment: please draw a diagram of how you want everything connected ... right now, all we know is that the computer and modem are connected together by some type of cable

Comment: You want to connect the ESP32 to the "modem" over the modem's wireless, then the modem to the computer over an Ethernet cable? Then you need to configure the "modem" appropriately. We can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use an FTDI programmer and communicate with a serial protocol like UART.
The connection schematic can be found here.
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/program-upload-code-esp32-cam/
However you would have to do some extra research work on making the serial communication with the ESP32.

So a nice way would be to buy a wifi module for your old computer and use it to connect to the wifi and program the ESP32 accordingly.